# How to get an img url using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get the actual URL (as opposed to the `src` attribute value) of an image within the current DOM using jQuery or JavaScript?

i.e. retrieve "example.com/foo.jpg" as opposed to "foo.jpg" (taking `<base>` elements into account)

What about any other interesting properties such as the mime type, file size or, best of all, the actual binary data?

Comment: http://example.com/foo.jpg as opposed to "foo.jpg" (taking <base> elements into account)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I wonder if jQuery is using `.getAttribute()` - using .src always seems to give the absolute URL:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" id="i">

<script>
var img = document.getElementById('i');

alert(img.getAttribute('src')); // foo.jpg
alert(img.src);                 // http://..../foo.jpg
</script>
```

To get the rest of the information, could you use an AJAX request and look at the header & data sent?

Comment: To do this with a Jquery selector use: $(selector).get(0).src;

Comment: Good thinking Greg, cheers. As for the rest, I was hoping I might be able to do something without extra AJAX round trips, given that it should already be loaded, and avoiding any cross site AJAX issues would be good too.

Comment: Now I can use this to grab the value of `src` to homepage using `amp-iframe`.

Answer (score 15):

***$(you IMG selector).attr('src');***

for instance, if we have an `<img src='bla-bla.jpg' id='my_img'>`

then we'll do:

```
$('#my_img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var img = $('img');
alert(img.attr('src')); // foo.jpg
var fullpath = window.location.host + img.attr('src');
alert(fullpath); // http://example.com/foo.jpg
```

Comment: How is this helpful? What are you doing there? Please explain so people might learn something, your answer is not very clear to beginners.

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
$("#my_img").src;
```

just it resolve the problem