# filereader access web image

Tags: javascript, filereader

The code below works well if I as use it to select an image from a local pc:

```
var outerImg=document.getElementById("img");

    if(!outerImg.files[0])
    {
        return;
    }
    var imgdat=outerImg.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload=function(event)
    {
        var img=new Image; 
            img.onload=function()
        {
            doThings(this);
        }
            img.src=event.target.result;
            alert(img.src);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(imgdat);
```

My question is, is it possible to use a similar way to access a web image? Lets say I have 10 images and display them using `<img src="xxx.jpg" id="img1">` and use reader to access them?

Comment: If this is Javascript (don't kill me if it isn't), please add the tag :)

Comment: If you have the JQuery library accessible, simply do $("myDiv").append("<img src='XXX.jpg' id='img1'); make sure you have a div to put it into.

Comment: HI, you mean this is possible? as long as we use jquery?  actually the web image is from my server which store inside MySQL and I would like to allow user to access each image to do image processing.

Comment: If this code is attatched to a webpage (inside the web page), then create a div tag or some element that will hold your image. After the image has been loaded, put it into the div tag using the code I provided. This is being executed via a website right?

Comment: Yes!  correct.  I just tried and out the image inside id=myDiv using your code.  However, it shows me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined .  I am sorry, I am pretty new about HTML5 API, please advise.

Comment: JQuery is not HTML5, its a library which simplifies a lot of the Javascript making website development quicker and simpler. You have to import the library. Add the following to your "head" tag <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script> also make sure you have the Div tag on your page. Here, let me post this as an answer so it easier for you to see.

Comment: yes the image can display properly using jQuery and I know what it is.  Of course  I link the library as well.  Now the image is inside #myDiv which is ok.  So how can I access this image using FileReader?

Comment: try this var outerImg=$("#img1");

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined   same error I replace var outerImg=document.getElementById("img1"); into var outerImg=$("#img1");

Comment: hmmm... did the error happen when you changed the code or was it like that before?

Comment: for local upload file, it works well.  Just if I want to access web image, it shows this error.  So I suspect, filereader cannot access web image.  isn't  it?

Comment: Aaah, ok. Derp I am an idiot. You cannot select a page element and upload it because page elements are not actual files they are markup. You can try and see if you could get the file location of the file, for instance "mysite/myImg.jpg" or the full URL might work aswell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788957/how-to-get-an-img-url-using-jquery this will help you get the full life location of the file

Comment: now i use var img = document.getElementById('img1');

alert(img.getAttribute('src')); // foo.jpg
alert(img.src);
   
// var outerImg=document.getElementById("img1");
var outerImg=$(img.src); 
it shows http://www.xx.com/abc.jpg<--my actual location, correct!  but Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined still exists

Comment: var outerImg=$(img.src); is probably causing it. Trying removing the $ and the ( ). The $ incapsulation is looking for the element on the page even though your passing in the image source location.

Comment: i am exhausted  I have rewrite var outerImg=img.src; still got the '0' problem....and I really appreciate your followup too and sorry to cause your time.

Comment: Could you post your code onto http://jsfiddle.net/ I could debug and tell you exactly what the problem is that way

Comment: oh I never try jsfiddle.net and not sure i can right or not.  you can edit it  http://jsfiddle.net/CaRdB/4/

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/CaRdB/33/

Comment: no error and no response either.  How can I know it works?  Can I dump the data to check?

Comment: If the file reader returns anything, you can always alert the result.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CaRdB/38/ try this..I try to dump the result out alert("imgdat"+imgdat); shows correct link but alert("imgsrc="+img.src); no response and in my web server it shows undefined image.  strange

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `files` property on an image element. That should explain the javascript error you're getting before you even get to the FileReader bit.

Comment: hello, I suspect this causes problem too.  So is it possible to access the image using FileReader?

Comment: I'm not positive, but after you fix the js error you could try using the img element directly like this `reader.readAsDataURL(outerImg);`

Comment: hm..try to remark the [0] stuff and use your suggestion, no response.

Comment: Then I'm guessing the answer to your question is no.

Comment: so your conclustion is FileReader can only deal with local file but not"http://xx" like file.

Comment: It's just my guess.  I haven't done anything but look here: [MDN: FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader)

Comment: from your link, it said "lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer" so seems can only access local file.  In this sense, can we download the image from web becomes local first and upload to process?  if yes, how?